# Folder Hierarchy

Tags: document, folder

Is it possible to color code folders (SharePoint 2007, no MOSS)?

For example if I want all of my Top level folders to be red, Level 2 to be blue etc. can I do this as I create a folder and can each folder be done individually as it's created?

Comment: Not out of the box, but it could possibly be done with some nicely written JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use some metadata to drive custom XSLT which would colour-code the folders - or maybe use XSLT to derive the folder level and apply colour-coding.

However, I tend to agree with Robert that JS or jQuery is probably your best option.  Maybe try something like

```
fileRef.split("/").length;
```

where fileRef is a variable populated with the path of the folder, this would give you a way to compare the folder levels though you would need to establish the count at the base level.